# An image concealed in Spiral Galaxies

Tags: visual

#### What is the image in this (colored) Spiral Galaxies puzzle?

[image: spiral galaxy puzzle] 
 $\rightarrow \text{_ _ _}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution to the puzzle is:

> [image]

and coloring in the regions based on their dots gives the answer:

> [image]
>
>  It looks to be an **EGG**.